# S3_delete_objects_operator does not delete files in the bucket

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I have implemented S3DeleteObjectsOperator, but even though task shows key deleted successfully, in reality the object does not get deleted from the S3 bucket.

```
delete_s3bucket_files = S3DeleteObjectsOperator(
  task_id='delete_s3bucket_files',
  start_date=start_date,
  bucket='****',
  keys='******************',
  aws_conn_id='aws_default',
)
```

Even though the task is getting completed as passed, it does not delete objects inside the specified key in the bucket. I can see the logs below:

```
[2019-09-26 14:19:15,554] {base_task_runner.py:101}INFO - Job 1435: Subtask delete_s3bucket_files [2019-09-26 14:19:15,553] {cli.py:517} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: test_s3_delete.delete_s3bucket_files 2019-09-26T12:18:59.362470+00:00 [running]> on host Saurav-macbook.local
[2019-09-26 14:19:15,883] {s3_delete_objects_operator.py:83} INFO - Deleted: ['******************']
```

How can I understand what the task is performing and why does the object does not get deleted?

Comment: **[1]** Was an `S3DeleteObjectOperator` really required, given that `S3Hook` already exposes a [`delete_objects()` method](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L602) (which you could've invoked in `python_callable` of a `PythonOperator`)? **[2]** This doesn't look like an `Airflow` issue; rather a `python` / `botocore` / `boto3` environment issue or AWS permissions (*credentials-profile* / IAM role) issue. Did you check if you are able to accomplish the same delete functionality by running your code via `Python` shell (from same machine as `Airflow`)?

Comment: Thanks, I tried with S3Hook delete_objects() method as well but couldn't get the files deleted. Instead I just used the boto3 delete() method to delete the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I couldn't get the object deletion working with `S3DeleteObjectOperator` as well as the `delete_objects()` method in `S3Hook`. So instead I used the `boto3` `delete()` method to delete the object.

```
def delete_files():
  s3 = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id='****', aws_secret_access_key='******************')
  s3_bucket = s3.Bucket('****')
  s3_bucket.objects.all().delete()


delete_s3bucket_files = PythonOperator(
  task_id='delete_s3bucket_files',
  start_date=start_date,
  python_callable=delete_files,
  dag=dag
)
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do, but works for me as of now.

Comment: **[1]** are you sure the credentials (`aws_secret_access_key_id` & `aws_secred_access_key`) were properly set in [default aws-conn](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L53)? Personally i prefer using `IAM Roles` attached to the EC2 machine on which `Airflow` task is running for authorization rather than credentials. **[2]** another thing is that this could be a region issue, since `S3_Hook` doesn't pass any region while [instantiating `s3_client`](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/S3_hook.py#L67)

Answer (score 1):

I'm also facing the same issue, like the dag is getting success but that partition is still there.
At last, i found out that I'm not passing the keys properly
Like x is your bucket name with object as y/year/2021/07
So,
bucket='x'
keys='y/year/2021/07'
You have to pass the complete path of the object in the keys **without s3://x**,
It'll work fine after this

```
delete_s3bucket_files = S3DeleteObjectsOperator(  task_id='delete_s3bucket_files',bucket='x',keys='y/year/2021/07',aws_conn_id='aws_default',dag=dag)
```

Comment: Still its not working for me, getting "ERROR - Failed to execute job 1288 for task delete_files". Is it a bucket delete access issue?

Answer (score 0):

you could try to use it this way using `prefix`:

```py
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.operators.s3 import S3DeleteObjectsOperator

clear_s3_with_prefix_task = S3DeleteObjectsOperator(
    task_id="clear_s3_with_prefix_task",
    bucket=<s3_bucket_name>,
    # All objects matching this prefix in the bucket will be deleted:
    prefix=<your_s3_path>,
    aws_conn_id=<s3_conn_id>',
    dag=dag
)
```